# error starting apache2 on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.4

Apache will not start.  The command "sudo service apache2 status" lists these errors:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 1: /usr/sbin/apachectl: id: not found
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 98: [: -eq: unexpected operator
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 147: /usr/sbin/apachectl: mkdir: not found
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 126: /usr/sbin/apachectl: mktemp: not found
/usr/sbin/apachectl: 127: /usr/sbin/apachectl: chmod: not found
```

I checked this against the version of apachectl on a test machine and it is the same code.  I tried running with sh, bash and dash ... but none worked.  I don't think there is anything actually wrong with apachectl but something in my setup must be wrong.

Any idea how I can fix this error?

System ubuntu 19.04, apache 2.4

Comment: what is the output of `which mkdir` or  `which \[`  ?

Comment: It looks as Your path or access permissions are broken or even some basic commands are missing. How did You try to start explicitly with sh or bash? At that place, check whether You can execute or find the mentioned binaries (i.e. `which id`, `which apachectl`, `echo $PATH`, `ls -l /usr/bin/id`)...

Comment: the first line is of apache2ctl is   #!/bin/sh 
and  
ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 May 20  2016 /bin/sh -> dash

how does it look like at your system?

Comment: the trouble starts in envvars right after the line export PATH="/var/www/.local/bin"

Answer (score 0):

The trouble was I destroyed the path.  The PATH export should have read

```
export PATH=$PATH:/var/www/.local/bin
```